# Newline and indent in Emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation

So I've got a problem with Emacs. I want it to make an indent everytime i press ENTER. It works, but it does only 2 spaces, and I want it to do 4, like TAB. Here's my indentation configuration:

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command);
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

What should I change?

Comment: Try customizing the `tab-width` variable rather then `setq-default`ing it.

Comment: The number of columns for indenting is generally set on a per-major-mode basis (e.g. `c-basic-offset` or `python-indent-offset`).  `tab-width` probably won't affect the indent offset in any mode.

Comment: @jpkotta Yeah, thanks! Works for both of those!